# How to change color with mutiple iif

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have text box expression below, the result look like this:

Newtoy - Oldtoy - Notoy

I can get all text to become blue color,  but I want the "dash sign" (-) become black color.

My expression is incorrect . Can you help to see what went wrong. Thank you.

```
="font color = 'blue' size = '1'" 
& iif(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2") = " " ,"None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))+ "/font",

= iif(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2") = "-" ,"black", "blue",
```

And this is the query populating the dataset:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT CAST(b.branch as varchar) +' '+ ' | ' +' ' 
FROM printers p 
full join branch b on p.branchid = b.branchid 
where p.printername is null 
order by b.branch FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),2,1,'');
```

Comment: Still not really sure what you're going for here.  You want the dash to always be black?  Or only on certain circumstances?  Are you expecting the ID field to return a dash rather than a digit?  Might be helpful to provide some sample of the data that ID will return so I can figure out what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, the dash needs black and the rest of text need blue.                                 the return  like  this  Newtoy - Oldtoy - Notoy

Comment: To clarify, `Fields!ID.Value` returns `Newtoy - Oldtoy - Notoy –` and you want only the dashes in black?

Comment: Also, will there be only 2 dashes or potentially more than 2?

Comment: the dash will in the middle of text. Might more dash if more data enter. For example xxxxxxx - zzzzzzzz -ccccccccc - bbbbbbbbbb and No extra dash at the end.

Comment: This issue would be a lot easier if the data was formatted from the DB in a better way.  For only 2 dashes, you could use `GetChar((Fields!ID.Value), InStr((Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"),"-"))` to select the first dash and `GetChar((Fields!ID.Value), InStrRev((Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"),"-"))` to select the last dash, but if there's more than 2 dashes, I haven't found a solution to grab any additional dashes.  Perhaps some combination of `MID` with `InStr`, but it's a complex expression.  Ideally, you would modify the data to simplify the results in the report.

Comment: To explain, `InStr` searches the first parameter(`Fields!ID.Value`) for the value provided in the second parameter(`"-"`) and returns the position of that character.  `InStrRev` does the same from the end of the string.  It only grabs the first value, however.  `GetChar` then uses the result of `InStr` to return the character at that position from `Fields!ID.Value`.

Comment: this query from dataset to get the value  SELECT STUFF((SELECT CAST(b.branch as varchar) +' '+ '  |  ' +' '
  FROM printers p
  full join branch b on p.branchid = b.branchid where p.printername is null order by b.branch
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),2,1,'');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so now that I see why the data is formatted as it is, I've found a solution that should work for you.  Basically, to make this work, you'll need to modify the query from the dataset to the following:

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(b.branch, 'None') as varchar)
FROM printers p 
FULL JOIN branch b ON p.branchid = b.branchid WHERE p.printername IS NULL 
ORDER BY b.branch
```

This will provide the `b.branch` values in a way that they can be joined in SSRS with font formatting in between each value.  It also accounts for `NULL` values with the `ISNULL` function which will check each `ID` and select `NULL` values as `None` when it returns the values.

The expression should begin with the font color set to blue.  Next, you'll need to use two SSRS functions, `LookupSet` will return all of the values of `Fields!ID.Value` in an array which we can put into one string with `Join`.  `Join` requires values to join and a delimiter, which in this case is your chance to format the text color correctly. Delimiting by `"</font><font color = 'black' size = 1>-</font><font color = 'blue' size = 1>"` will close the first `<font>` tag which should make the first `ID` blue, inserts a black dash, and opens a new `<font>` tag for the next `ID`, and so on.  Finally, you add a closing `</font>` tag to finish coloring the final `ID` in blue.

```
="<font color = 'blue' size = 1>" 
& Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"), "</font><font color = 'black' size = 1>-</font><font color = 'blue' size = 1>") & "</font>"
```

I've tested this and it seems to work as it should.  However, you'll need to be sure that you use this expression in a Placeholder with Markup type set to HTML to Interpret HTML tags as styles for this to work.

Here's an example of how it looks when I use the expression above with a lighter color to demonstrate:

[image: example]

Comment: Let me try something

Comment: @Tsang Just added an image of what happens when I use the expression on a dataset I have for reference.

Comment: I don't know how you can figure it out but You're so smart. It's working well. Thank you for help. I owe you a cup of coffee.